# @OneToMany working in Jpa. How are we able to retrieve the List of entities?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am having two entities Course and Instructor. An Instructor can have many courses but a course can be assigned to only one Instructor.

I add some courses to the instructor. So these courses are being added to the ArrayList right due to the following method addCourses :

```
public void addCourses(Course course) {
        if(courses==null) {
            courses=new ArrayList<Course>();
        }
        courses.add(course);
        course.setInstructor(this);
    }
```

So I am asking where is this ArrayList getting saved. When I want to retrieve the List of courses I am able to do so by using the courses ArrayList. But I don't see any database table getting generated to save this list. How am I able to retrieve this list then?

Course

```
@Entity
@Table(name="course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String title;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade=      {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="instructor_id")
    private Instructor instructor;

    //getters and setters and constructor
    
}
```

Instructor

```
@Entity
@Table(name="instructor")
public class Instructor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="instructor", cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private List<Course> courses;


    //adding a convenience method for bi-directional relationship
    public void addCourses(Course course) {
        if(courses==null) {
            courses=new ArrayList<Course>();
        }
        courses.add(course);
        course.setInstructor(this);
    }
    
        // getters and setters and constructors
}
```

Comment: You don't need any extra table to map a 1-to-many relation. It will simply create a foreign key on the "many" part linking to the 1. In your case the Course table will have a column instructor_id linking your coursed to the instructors. That all that is needed to  create Lists when doing a query.

Comment: My main query is How am I able to retrieve this List of courses if it is not stored in the database?

Comment: But it is stored in the database. Just not in any extra table because an extra table is not needed.

Comment: ok there is no extra table but it is getting stored somewhere in the database right. Actually I asked this doubt to a person he told its not stored in database.

Comment: I already explained that the relationship is stored as a foreign key on the "many" side. This is what is used to store your relationship that on the java side is represented by a list. In your example each database row of `course` will have a `instructor_id` column that points to the `instructor` table. So for example if you want the List of courses that the instructor with id=3 has you can get that with a query like`select * from course where instructor_id=3`.  All this is of course done by JPA in the background but this is how your relationship is stored.